# Google Sheets 3D Spreadsheet - Linking headers between sheets

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

I'm trying to create a 3D spreadsheet in Google Sheets. i.e. I want more than one piece of data in each cell. I accomplish this I'm trying to spread one dimension across sheets.

Is there a way to keep multiple sheets with identical formatting of the frozen column and row, allowing different data to be entered into each?

That is, I can add/remove/format the top column/row in one and the others are updated accordingly.

Comment: As far as I know it's impossible to automatically change format in all sheets without scripts. The easiest way to make multiple sheets is by copying source sheet as many times as you need.

Comment: Are you open to using [Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/overview). I think that's the only way to programmatically propagate changes in frozen column/row to other sheets.